# Divide js array in 2 components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array and I want to be able to divide it in 2 components, so like the first 5 elements go in one element and whatever is left go in the second element. I know I have to use slice and I can get the first component but not sure about the second one.

I have something like this:

```
if (item.children) {
  return item.children.slice(0, 5).map((childItem) => {
    const navItem = (
      <Link activeClassName={styles.active} to={childItem.url}>{childItem.text}</Link>
    )
    return (
      <li key={childItem.id}>
        {navItem}
      </li>
    )
  })
}
```

So how do I get another component to appear after, like

```
<li key={childItem.id}>
   {navItem}
</li>
{navExtra}
```

that contains all the remaining elements from the array?

The final html should look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <!-- // first five elements of the array -->
    <li><a href="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
    <!-- // new component  -->
    <li>
      <button>Extra</button>
      <ul>
        <!-- // remaning elements of the array -->
        <li><a href="Item 6">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="Item 7">Item 7</a></li>
        <!-- // etc -->
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please describe your  problem clearly & detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Variables will really help your code readability here. `slice(beginIndex, endIndex)` and `slice(begin)` are the keys.

You already know `slice(0,5)` will get you the first half of the array.

`var x = slice(5)` will get you the components of the array from the fifth element to the end. You can call `map()` and do any other processing on these elements to get something to display.

[MSDN docs for slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

When you use splice, it alters the original array, essentially leaving you item.children with all of the elements you want to include in `navExtra`

We can create a return object that holds `navItems` and `navExtra` separately for you to render separately, adding the wrapping `<ul>` in the render, etc.

```
if (item.children) {
  let ret = {
    navItems: [],
    navExtra: []
  };
  navItems = item.children.splice(0, 5);

  ret.navItems.push(
    navItems.map(navItem => {
      return (
        <li key={navItem.id}>
          <Link activeClassName={styles.active} to={navItem.url}>{navItem.text}</Link>
        </li>
      )
    })
  )

  ret.navExtra.push(
    item.children.map(navExtra => {
      <li key={navExtra.id}>
         <Link activeClassName={styles.active} to={navExtra.url}>{navExtra.text}</Link>
      </li>
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: ok but I don't think this does what I'm looking for, cause I'm already rendering the first part of the array... what I want to do is to get whatever is left of the array into a new component.

Comment: ah - no problem. what is the new component called/look like to instantiate?

Comment: looking at your example again, I'm guessing this is what `navExtra` is assigned to?  so can you show me how you would create this (e.g., which props you pass in and where their values are referenced from)?

Comment: Yeah so the question is how do I get the remaining elements of the array to be rendered in navExtra, this will be a different list element. So I don't know how to do that, that's why is not there in my code snippet

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect what I think it is you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML element with `appendChild`. Here is an example of how you could do what you are trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="div1">
</div>

<script>
var array = ["this", "is", "a", "random", "array", "that", "i", "just", "made"];
var splitBy = Math.round(array.length / 2);

//for first half
for (var i = 0; i <= splitBy; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
    li.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(li);
}
//for second half
for (var i = splitBy + 1; i < array.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
    li.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(li);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is using React, so they're not going to want to manually append elements directly to the DOM.

Comment: oh, ok. Should I delete my answer?